# How to loop through all elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I have images and have to count facebook shares for each image. I can't make loop for that. It's now for only one element. How to do that?
My code is:

```js
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
         var current = 0;
         $count = $('#count_bombs').val();
         $('#' + current).each(function() {
          var id = $('#' + current).val(); console.log(id);
          $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com/images/view/' + id, function(data) { 
             document.getElementById("shares_count_" +current).innerHTML = data.shares;
            console.log(data.shares);  console.log("#shares_count_" +current);
          });
          current++;
         });

        });
        </script>
```

```html
        <?php $num=0;  $id = 0; ?> 
          <?php foreach($images as $key=>$val){  ?>
        <div>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo URL::base();?>images/view/<?php echo $val['image_name'];?>">
        <span aria-hidden="true"  class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>
         <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="count" value="<?php echo $val['image_name'];?>">
         SHARE 
        </a>
         </div>

        <div>
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true" ></span> 
         <span id="shares_count_<?php echo $id; ?>"></span>
         <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo count($bombs);?>" id="count_bombs" name="count_bombs">
       </div>
```

Edited: I did it. I used `index` parameter of each method. This is my code:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var current = 0;
 $("input[type=hidden]").each(function(index, element){
  var id = $('#' + current).val();
  $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/http://pbombd.dev/bombs/view/' + id, function(data) { 
     $('#shares_count_' + index).html(data.shares);
  });
  current++;
 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hint: Instead of id selector in each, try using class selector..

Answer (score 1):

`$('#' + count)` will returns only one element so can't loop on it. It seems like you want to find every hidden input with the css class `count` in your page. You can do it like this :

```
$('input.count').each(function() {
    $input = $(this);

    // $input contains the hidden input
    console.log($input.attr('id));
});
```

Comment: I think jQuery has a find method which returns an array of elements matching the selector. Then maybe just doing $(rootEl).find(selector).length ?